# Resolve Nextjs URL to a selected component

Tags: javascript, next.js

From what I understand [Nextjs](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/) resolves URLs by mapping them to their respective file in `pages` folder. So `pages/about-us.js` will be accessable via `href="/about-us"`.

I want to create multiple languages but don't wanna duplicate the necessary components/JS files. So assuming I have an `about-us.js` with following content:

```
<Head title={meta}/>
<Nav/>

<MainContent language={lang}/>
<Footer/>
```

How can I map `/pl/about-us` to the `/about-us`.js in the root of pages without creating another `about-us`.js in `/pages/pl/..`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solution I can think of is to pass the language as a query param

Example

```
// code for page/about-us.js page
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';

const AboutUs = ({ router }) => {
  const { lang } = router.query;

  return <div>Welcome to next.js! Language = {lang}</div>;
};

export default withRouter(AboutUs);
```

so If you got to `about-us?lang=pl` it will show

```
Welcome to next.js! Language = pl
```

---

Or instead of parsing language inside every page, you can use [custom app.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-app) with the code something like this

```
// custom _app.js
import React from 'react'
import App, { Container } from 'next/app'

export default class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, router, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {}

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }

    return { pageProps }
  }

  state = {
    language: undefined
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { router } = this.props;

    this.setState({ language: router.query.lang });
  }

  render () {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props

    return (
      <Container>
        <Component {...pageProps} language={this.state.langugage} />
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

so every page will have `language` passed as a param.

Hope this helps.

UPDATE:

to make a custom routing you need to check [disabling file-system routing](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#disabling-file-system-routing) and write some [custom server routing](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#custom-server-and-routing)

Comment: thanks but I want to map the routes because resources are better than query strings for SEO.

Comment: oh I see. I guess this way you will need to check [disabling file-system routing](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#disabling-file-system-routing) and write some [custom server routing](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#custom-server-and-routing)

Comment: @yayokk perfect, the latter works fine. Maybe you can amend the answer.